# How to create a block transition in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition, effect

What is the best way to create a block transition in jQuery? Are there any plugins, who provide this transition (only the transition, I don't want a image gallery, which has such a transition!)?

I am looking for something like http://mitya.co.uk/scripts/Blockster-transition-effect-122 or the diagonal expand block transition at http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-banner-rotator-slideshow/full_screen_preview/109046

Problem with the first link is, that it is very slow, when using a bit more blocks. I can't figure out how the transition has been created on the second link.

Answer (score 1):

if you add this code to the blockster.js on line 144 you will have more blocks fading simultaneously.

```
/* ------------------
| ANIMATION - with all blocks built, set an interval to turn them all on, one by one.
| When all blocks in position, and all have finished anim (if fade rather than simple)
|   - kill int
|   - shuffle slides so the one our blocks contain parts of is genuinely topmost
|   - remove blocks
------------------ */
    var simultaneous = 5;
for(var i = 0; i < simultaneous; ++i)
{
    addTimer(nextSlide, thiss, i, simultaneous);
}
}

function addTimer(nextSlide, thiss, i, simultaneousBlocks)
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
    var animInt = setInterval(function() 
        {
        if(thiss.params.holder.children('.block:not(:visible)').length > 0)     
            {
            var blocks = thiss.params.holder.children('.block:not(:visible)');
        with($(blocks.get(!thiss.params.random ? 0 : Math.floor(Math.random() * blocks.length)))) thiss.params.animType == 'simple' ? show() : fadeIn(thiss.params.blockAnimSpeed);
    }
    else if ($('.block:animated').length == 0) 
            {
        clearInterval(animInt);
        nextSlide.siblings().hide();
        nextSlide.show();
        $('.block').remove();
        }
    }, thiss.params.blockAnimSpeed);
}, (thiss.params.blockAnimSpeed / simultaneousBlocks) * i);     
}
```